# c++ boost lambda libraries

Tags: c++, functional-programming, boost-lambda

What might be the best way to start programming using boost lambda libraries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remaining within the boundaries of the C++ language and libraries, I would suggest first getting used to programming using STL algorithm function templates, as one the most common use you will have for boost::lambda is to replace functor classes with inlined expressions inlined.

The library documentation itself gives you an up-front example of what it is there for:

```
for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), std::cout << _1 << ' ');
```

where `std::cout << _1 << ' '` produces a function object that, when called, writes its first argument to the `cout` stream. This is something you could do with a custom functor class, `std::ostream_iterator` or an explicit loop, but boost::lambda wins in conciseness and probably clarity -- at least if you are used to the functional programming concepts.

When you (over-)use the STL, you find yourself gravitating towards boost::bind and boost::lambda. It comes in really handy for things like:

```
std::sort( c.begin(), c.end(), bind(&Foo::x, _1) < bind(&Foo::x, _2) );
```

Before you get to that point, not so much. So use STL algorithms, write your own functors and then translate them into inline expressions using boost::lambda.

From a professional standpoint, I believe the best way to get started with boost::lambda is to get usage of boost::bind understood and accepted. Use of placeholders in a boost::bind expression looks much less magical than "naked" boost::lambda placeholders and finds easier acceptance during code reviews. Going beyond basic boost::lambda use is quite likely to get you grief from your coworkers unless you are in a bleeding-edge C++ shop.

Try not to go overboard - there *are* times when and places where a `for`-loop *really* is the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. Are you already well versed in functional programming concepts? If not, I'd suggest that you start in a language that is designed for functional programming instead of a procedural language with functional features stapled on. If you aren't used to coding in a functional style (it's not *harder* necessarily, but it's definitely different), then you'll spend more time fighting the syntax and not enough time learning to get stuff done.

As for where to start, I cut my functional teeth on Scheme, but there are plenty of good options.

Comment: If you are already familiar with C-style syntax, I would recommend Erlang as far as functional languages go - it's a more familiar syntax and the general structure is similar, so you spend less time confused and more time programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a reasonably recent compiler, you can use boost.  If it's not on your machine already, install it (sudo apt-get install libboost-dev on unbuntu, get the binaries from boost.org if you are on windows).  Read the [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/lambda.html)'s then look at your existing code for situations where you might use them.  Do you have a lot of code duplication that could be eliminated if you parametrized a function with a small piece of code, for example?