# boost::function and boost::bind are cool, but what is really cool about boost::lambda?

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, boost-lambda

On Page 175 Paragraph 1 of [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0321334876/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=471057153&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0201924889&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1Y528C3FPJF02HTV2JBG) Meyers has this to say about generalized functors and binding:

> I find what `tr1::function` lets you do
>   so amazing, it makes me tingle all
>   over. If you're not tingling , it may
>   be because you're staring at the
>   definition of ... and wondering what's
>   going on with the ....

And I agree with him on bind and function. About lambda, Well I understand what lambda does and how it does it, but could someone post a book style mind-blowing snippet or a verbal outline of why lambda is supposed to (in Meyers' terminology) blow my socks off ? I ask because each area of C++ where the placeholder syntax is used seems like a hack to me (yes, I know enough about the functional method, **so please no basics**), I agree with the way it's used in bind and MPL; However, in the case of lambda I just want it justified so I can decide weather I should enter it into my repertoire.

-- edit --

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133837/c-boost-lambda-libraries/135367#135367) mentions the inlined creation of a functor using just placedholder syntax, he mentions advanced usage, and this is probably what I am after... in advanced usage is it still just inlined creation of functors ?

Comment: Did you read the BLL documentation? There are tons of examples that blew my mind off the first time I read it. E.g: `sort(a, b, _1 < _2);`. And then search SO.

Comment: (+1) Yep, I did (at least the first 10 pages) -- and I understand that form of usage. Is this it though ?

Comment: Lambdas are all about inline creation of anonymous functions and Boost.Lambda gave you tools to do that before C++0x lambdas inclusion was even discussed - so i wouldn't say *"thats it?"*. *(hey, don't claim my +1 ;)*

Comment: BB and BLL evolved separately, hence the overlap. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/lambda/s08.html -- that should clear any confusion.

Comment: Thanks guys: you should have made answers though =D, but it would have been hard to accept any of the three answers. I think I will use lambda for the simple stuff -- I was only reading the documentation because I was following the reference from spirit. I wish they would hard-wire functional programming into the language -- including spirit brings my compiler to it's knees.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hard-wiring, but with the next standard a big chunk of Boost will be shipped to you automagically. The lambda syntax is a bit of a horror though: for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&sum](int x) {sum += x;}); -- so beware. Try precompiling the boost headers -- that ought to give you joy.

Comment: @dirkgently thanks -- I would have thought pre-compilation didn't bother with template code. I've got most of the headers I need to write grammars using the rule approach in spirit precompiled.... Under Visual Studio the pch file takes 128 MB of space. What I meant by hardwired -- is that the language should allow TMP constructs to be represented so that the compiler doesn't have to generate 128 MB worth of internal data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments left above, and the link in the question, the following is the answer I accept (community wiki) :

1. Boost.Lambda fills the purpose of inline functor creation (that's the term I like). This functionality can be filled by Function + Bind, but it is more verbose than it needs to be, and for simple functors this is unnecessary — e.g., the sort shown in the comments above.
2. There is obviously semantic overlap between the Function-Bind pair and Lambda — this is a historical artifact, and because Lambda has its *raison d'être*, it exists in Boost.

Answer (score 0):

What is "cool" about it is that, as with *boost foreach* and *boost parameter*, injects/extends syntax into C++ which is not in the language, ie it emulates anonymous functions directly as parameters.

Comment: Well, the alternative would be to write your own compiler with your own invented language.

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way ima, it's not why use C++ at all, it's why isn't this part of the C++ syntax yet. The C++0x lambda expressions are really cool, but they're only just a small step towards compiler-supported iterators and iterating over them.